# How to install emulators in VS2017 Cordova (Windows 10)

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2017, android-emulator

I am playing around with VS2017 and Cordova, when I try to run on the emulator the drop down just says "Install Emulators". I've tried to click that and it does nothing and the install message remains.

How do I install the emulators VS is looking for please.

I have installed VS 2017 on a Windows laptop with Android Studio to see if this fixes but it doesn't

Would appreciate any pointers please.

Answer (score 0):

Well i gave up with vs 2017 and got the cordova cli working instead. I suspect it is the paths because it does involve a lot of trial and error. Youtube channel by steve griffiths eventually gave me some clues.